# What's the difference when we define delegate in the class or out of it?

Tags: c#, delegates

in fact,What's the difference when we define delegate in the class or out of it ?I am a Beginner, please explain simple.

Example 1

```
namespace Delegate
{
    public delegate int Calculate(int value1, int value2);
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Example 2

```
class Program
{
    public delegate int Calculate(int value1, int value2);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189289/why-can-we-declare-delegates-outside-a-class-is-it-not-against-oop-concept

Comment: In short your answer would be you could repeatedly use the same delegate template in many classes rather than just the one

Comment: @Alex,http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx

Comment: its like having nested class in class. if the delegate is just related to that class then write it in, if not then write it out side. no difference in practice.

Comment: You should use the first approach, [according to Micirosoft's guidelines.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182162.aspx). (A delegate is a `type`, so it should not be nested unless it is private or protected.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference when we define delegate in the class or out of
>   it

When you define a delegate outside the class, and in no other class, it belongs to the namespace it was defined on. This means that if one wanted to use this delegate, the full path to it would look like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void H()
        {
            MyDelegate.Calculate y = (x, w) => 1;
        }
    }
}

namespace MyDelegate
{
    public delegate int Calculate(int value1, int value2);
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As opposed if you were to expose it inside a class, your path would contain the actual class that defined the delegate:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void H()
        {
            MyDelegate.Program.Calculate y = (x, w) => 1;
        }
    }
}

namespace MyDelegate
{   
    class Program
    {
        public delegate int Calculate(int value1, int value2);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

As @MatthewWatson points out in the comments, as `delegate` is a type, it should usually be declared at the namespace level, like `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` are in the .NET framework. If you want to implement a delegate which will internally be used inside a class hierarchy, you could potentially place it inside the class and set it as `protected`. I do recommend using the delegates mentioned above which are exposed by the .NET framework and fulfill most requirements.

Comment: Some guidance about what to use when would have been nice.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Done.